# In SSRS report need to strip chars from display field

Tags: regex, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Trying to strip chars from "InboundFlight" field in SSRS report. In this case "AS4310" needs to display as "4310" and "ASX721" AS "721". Tried the code below but end up with error: "report failed because report could not be built."  Intellisense doesn't know "Replace".. Any ideas on how to display only the numbers apart of a SSRS feild?

```
ArrivalDateTime       InboundFlight
15/01/2019  1:16PM    AS4310        
15/01/2019  4:54PM    4258      
15/01/2019  5:13PM    ASX721        
15/01/2019  5:20PM    6222      



 =System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(
  IIf(IsNothing(=Fields!InboundFlight.Value), "", Fields!InboundFlight.Value),
  "(\d+)","$1")
```

Error: Report failed because report could not be built.

Comment: IsMatch gave me a booleon = true

Comment: My apologies `=System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(Fields!OutboundFlight.Value, "\d+")`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I could not get the capturing group to work. This ended up working for my case.

```
=System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(Fields!InboundFlight.Value, "\D","")
```